# Clicking submit clears file field instead of submitting the form (IE9)

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, file-upload

I got a weird error I hope you guys can help with.

Sometimes when the user tries to submit a form the file upload field `image`  just clears and nothing happens. I doesn't seems like the form get submitted at all.

Then the day after everything works fine. The error occurs on random days/times.

First I thought it was a problem with the users computer but this happens on two different computers the customer has. One of the computers has Windows 7 professional & Internet Explorer 9. I don't have the setup on the other one.

I have tried with Google Chrome, Firefox 6.0.2, Internet Explorer 9, 8 (browser compatibility mode), 7 (browser compatibility mode) on windows 7 home with no problems at all on my computer.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/user/image" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form_default" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" name="save" value="submit" class="button">Save</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="image">Profile image</label><input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" name="save" value="submit" class="button">Save</button>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Attempts to submit the form for me.. I don't have a script to accept the form at /user/image though so it 404's

Comment: Have you found a solution to this bug? I'm experiencing the exact same thing...

Comment: Just out of curiosity - does this bug persist if you use <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" class="button" /> instead?

Comment: not sure about Cudos but in my case I'm already using an <input type="submit"> to submit the file upload form

Comment: Okay, for some reason removing the "name" attribute from the file input element seemed to alleviate the problem... still investigating...

Comment: I think removing the "name" attribute only works because it essentially removes the file element from the form dataset, resulting in an empty submission... so basically it only works because it breaks the form. This is frustrating.

Comment: It's definitely intermittent.

Comment: I never found a resolution on this one. Just learned to live it or use SWFupload or similar.

Comment: Have you looked in the "F12 Developer Tools" console for any errors?

Comment: yeah, I didn't see anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: Is there any JavaScript acting on the form in any way at all?

Comment: I wonder if you can see anything related to the "Activated submit button"? http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/interact/forms.html#successful-controls - "If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful."

Comment: How about just giving the submit buttons different names?

Comment: Submit button works for me. It is something that should not be blame to IE :D

Comment: Check for any javascript event bound to form submit or submit click.

Comment: There's some javascript acting on the form, but I've tried hooking an e.stopPropagation into the submit event so that it won't fall victim to some random "return false" higher up in the DOM, and it still won't work. I don't think this is an issue of e.preventDefault or anything like that.

Comment: Also, emphaticsunshine, the only browser that it happens in is IE, so I think I'm going to blame IE for this one. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only 1 `submit button` per `form`.
So keep 1 save button as `type="submit"` ,change another to `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using input instead of button, good luck!

ex

```
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Click!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
<input type="button" onclick="customFunction" />
```

write what you want to do in customFunction(javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There is no clever workarounds for this, IE9 does not allow a file to be tampered with via JavaScript probably for security reasons.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, pls let us see your php coding to send this form....
Usually form submission errors such as this have server-side coding errors..
Maybe you should check out your PHP coding and see what happens in your

```
 $_POST['save']
```

area....

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: The poster was pretty clear about having the problem before the form submits. In fact, they said the form doesn't appear to submit at all. I have the same issue, and it is definitely client-side.