# On form submit, file field clears in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I think this problem is related to this question:

[Clicking submit clears file field instead of submitting the form (IE9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513211/clicking-submit-clears-file-field-instead-of-submitting-the-form-ie9)

I have the following form and 1 IE9 user reporting an issue. They are able to browse and select a file from their computer. But when they click the button to submit the form the image field is cleared and thus the application returns the error to 'please select an image'.

I cannot replicate the problem.

#### Upload a Photo (Step 1 of 2)

```
    <div class="box-content">
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="galleryuploadform" action="">
    <table>
    <tbody><tr><td class="field_name" vAlign="top" width="70">Image: <span class="red_highlight">*</span></td><td><input name="photo_image" type="file"><br>
    <span class="form_hint">All images must be:</span>
        <ul><li class="form_hint"> JPEG format (.jpg at the end)</li>
             <li class="form_hint"> RGB format</li>
                <li class="form_hint">Images will be resized to 1000x1000 on the longest edge (large size) for <a href="http://www.ephotozine.com/e2signup">e2 members</a> and 600x600 (normal size) for standard members</li></ul>

    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="field_name" vAlign="top">Adult: </td><td><input name="photo_adult" value="1" type="checkbox"><br>
    <span class="form_hint">Tick if your photo contains adult material.<br>
<strong>Important:</strong> We do not accept pornographic images and reserve the right to delete such material. </span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colSpan="2" align="center">
    <input name="action" value="Upload Photo" type="hidden">
    <input onclick="submitform('galleryuploadform');display_white_box('photo_upload_lightbox');closeKeepAlive();" name="button" value="Upload Photo" type="button"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </form>


    <div class="clear"></div></div>
```

we have submitform() which submits the form, display_white_box() which displays a dialog box message with 'uploading' and closeKeepAlive() which is a fix related to Safari on Mac. I have gone a javascript approach for submit because if i didn't the animated gif in the uploading dialog box would not animate.

As I said, I can't replicate it on any machine or any other browser.

Comment: Could it be an anti-virus app?

Comment: maybe, i'm awaiting that info from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution. This an bug in Internet Explorer.

Comment: source? any links to official bug reports?

Answer (score 0):

Does your form work with a normal submit button?

It may be as Joshua Gossett said but I can't find any reference. So, I'm more asking about a JS conflict.

I don't think you should be putting an `onclick` event on a `submit` input.

A better way to do it would be to put an `onsubmit` attribute on the form and put a javascript function in it which dictates the action of the form when being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I came across the same problem and wanted to share what worked for me.

Edit your **.htaccess** file by putting this in the end:

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

I found the information [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/cannot-upload-files-using-internet-explorer-9/5724d921-ae71-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).

Comment: Doesn't this force IE9 to render the page as IE8?