# Submit button needs to be clicked twice on IE

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code to submit a form and call a PHP script.

```
<script>  
function handleBrowse()
{    
    $('#uploadedfile').click();
}

function displayFilePath(obj)
{ 
    document.getElementById('dummyFilePath').innerHTML = obj.value;
}
</script>


    <div id="dummyFilePath" class="dummyFilePath"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="handleBrowse();"/>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../php/uploader.php" method="POST" target="myiframe">
        <input type="file" id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" onchange="displayFilePath(this)" style="display:none"/>        
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>

    <iframe  name="myiframe" id="myiframe" src="" width=1 height=1 style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;bottom:2px;"></iframe>
```

In Firefox I would only have to click once to submit it. But in IE, I need to click twice!

Could you explain me why?

Please run [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKT3r/7/) on IE to see the problem.
You can clearly see that once you browse for a file to upload, unless you press the upload file button twice the form's action does not work.

PS: the double click issue in IE can be resolved as suggested in the answer below, but that would cause the uploaded file never to reach its destination (uploader.php); Only its name will

Comment: Not sure that it is the root cause of your problem, but you need to close the element mark : `<input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="handleBrowse();"/>`

Comment: And, as you are using JQuery, `document.getElementById('dummyFilePath').innerHTML = obj.value;`is equal to `$('dummyFilePath').html(obj.value);`. Also avoid inline JS to declare event like onClick.

Comment: Try to add a submit event on your form with JQuery http://api.jquery.com/submit/ then add an alert box in the callback and check if the alert is displaying the first time with IE. Also check the console for error (F12)

Comment: YEs, When I did that I was able to see the alert after the first submit, but only the second one calls the script :$

Comment: Take the iframe out of the form itself. Why are you messing with IE's head??

Comment: @skarlinski I did move the iframe out, no help

Comment: @senthilbp I tried reading that question, didn't really get it, but I don't think its related to what I am facing... Thanks for your efforts though :) This question is driving me mad...

Comment: If you remove the target= do you still get the same problem?  I'd try it but for some reason jsfiddle.net won't load in IE for me!!!

Comment: Just tried it on IE8 (I know, I know!) and it worked as expected.  What version of IE are you running?

Comment: IE > 8 have the problem

Comment: This is apparently a known IE issue. If you show the file input element and then use the browse button and choose a file as if it were still hidden. You will see the name of the file shown in the file input element but be cleared the first time you click on the submit button. This SO post, alnog with others, also talks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885684/on-form-submit-file-field-clears-in-internet-explorer-9

Comment: This is marked as dupe but it actually looks like a different reason. OP doesn't even do preventDefault! Sure, the code could be cleaner and this has unnecessarily many revs as well - but I don't think this is a dupe of the one that is marked as the potential answer! AND I don't think that this should be a community rev.

Comment: This may be old, but the solution to your questions can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input

Basically, the issue is display:none in the upload button, change it to be off screen using css (but visible)

Answer (score 2):

update your Function like this

```
function handleBrowse()
{   
    $('#uploadedfile').click();
    $('#uploadedfile').detach();
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: detach resolved the double click issue, but caused the uploader.php form not to receive the actual file (please look at the example posted in the question).

Comment: the script only received the name of the file. somehow detach() cleared the file from the form